# SQL Server - Recursive Query with dates

Tags: sql-server, recursive-query

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
id          sid     start           end
34011   10017   2006-01-11  2006-06-28
66          10017   2006-10-24  NULL
67          10017   2007-04-15  NULL
68          10017   2007-10-15  2007-12-31
71          10017   2008-04-15  NULL
72          10017   2008-10-15  NULL
69          10017   2009-04-16  NULL
70          10017   2009-10-15  2010-03-01
33022   10019   2005-09-01  2005-10-03
35425   10019   2006-03-15  2006-09-15
35555       10019   2006-10-01      NULL
79          10019   2006-12-01  2007-04-12
88          10019   2010-01-02      NULL
99          10019   2010-07-02      NULL
```

I need a query (I think recursive) that pulls the following

```
10017       2006-01-11        2006-06-28
10017       2006-10-24        2007-12-31
10017       2008-04-15        2010-03-01  
10019       2005-09-01        2005-10-03
10019       2006-03-15        2006-09-15
10019       2006-10-01        2007-04-12
10019       2010-01-02        NULL
```

The gist of the query is that I need a start and end range for across multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not the prettiest of code, but this will get the job done.

My test table was called `#results`, so you'll obviously want to replace that with your real table name.

```
-- First find the next endDate for any record with a null endDate 

select  [sid], startDate,
        (   select MIN(endDate) 
            from #results r 
            where r.[sid] = #results.[sid] 
              and r.endDate is not null 
              and r.endDate > #results.startDate
            group by r.[sid]
        ) as endDate
into #nullEndDates
from #results
where #results.endDate is null

-- Then union those results with records that have an endDate 
-- and get the min(startDate) for the unioned result

select [sid], min(StartDate) as startDate, endDate
from 
(       
    select [sid], min(StartDate) as startDate, endDate
    from #nullEndDates
    group by [sid], endDate

    union

    select [sid], startDate, endDate
    from #results
    where #results.endDate is not null

) results
group by [sid], endDate
order by [sid], min(startDate)
```

My first attempt was to use `LEAD()` to populate all the endDates based upon the next startDate.  I don't think that is what you wanted, but just in case:

```
select  [sid], 
        startDate, 
        isnull(endDate, LEAD(startDate) OVER (ORDER BY [sid])) as endDate
from #results
order by [sid], startDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below sql:

This is the concept:

1. Fix the id value, at the moment it is a mess.
2. create a mapping table to help us get the result.

**Note: Please recheck the sql (Table Name, field name etc)**

```
-- Declare TempData Table
declare @tempData table
(
  id int identity,
  [sid] int,
  start date,
  [end] date
);
-- Declare TempMapping Table
declare @tempMapping table
(
  id int identity,
  start_id int,
  end_id int
);

--Insert the data to @tempData, with new ID
insert into @tempData([sid],[start],[end])
select [sid],[start],[end] from @temp 
order by [sid],[start],[end]
;

--insert The Mapping value
insert into @tempMapping(start_id,end_id)
select 
    start_id , end_id
from
(
    select start_id, end_id
    , ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by end_id order by start_id) as xxrow
    from
    (
        select 
        a.id as start_id ,bb.id as end_id
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by a.id order by a.id) as xrow
        from 
        (
             select b.id, b.[sid],b.[start]
                from @tempData b
                where b.[end] is null
        ) a
        left join
        (
            select b.id, b.[sid],b.[start],b.[end]
            from @tempData b
            where b.[end] is not null
        ) bb on a.[sid] = bb.[sid] and a.[id]< bb.id

        group by 
        a.id, a.[sid],a.[start]
        ,bb.[id]
    ) c
    where c.xrow = 1
) d
where d.xxrow =1 
order by start_id, end_id
;
/*
select * from @tempMapping
--Table Mapping Result:
id          start_id    end_id
----------- ----------- -----------
1           2           4
2           5           8
3           11          12
4           13          NULL

*/


--Result Query
select 
    e.[id],e.[sid], e.[start],e.[end]
from @tempData e
left join @tempMapping f on f.end_id = e.id
where e.[end] is not null and f.id is null
union
select 
    start_id as id, b.sid, b.start, c.[end]
from @tempMapping a
left join @tempData b on a.start_id = b.id
left join @tempData c on a.end_id = c.id
```

Result Table:

```
id          sid         start      end
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
1           10017       2006-01-11 2006-06-28
2           10017       2006-10-24 2007-12-31
5           10017       2008-04-15 2010-03-01
9           10019       2005-09-01 2005-10-03
10          10019       2006-03-15 2006-09-15
11          10019       2006-10-01 2007-04-12
13          10019       2010-01-02 NULL
```